# how can I learn cocos2d—x

Tags: cocos2d-x

guys. recently i am trying to learn cocos2dx. coz i want to write game. but ive been search many resources. always hard to follow . maybe because im new to this. i know javascript. and i just want some good resources to study. can u please give me some resources like website or any thing that i can learn from. thanks in advance. ive tried many youtube links. there seems a lot of differemt ways in learning write games. i am very confusee
    if（you know any good resources for learning）
    ｛please tell me｝

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic here - [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the **official** programmers guide of cocos2d-x.
http://cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/

You are right, there are different ways of developing a game. If you ask two programmers to develop something you will have two different solutions. The solutions are different, one solution is faster and but the other one could be more secure.

I would advice you to use cocos2d-js because you already know javascript. And use the API Reference for cocos2d-js http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.7/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to notice, that if you already familiar with javascript, it can be easy for you to use cocos-js, instead of cocos2dx. As a guide for that you can use [this good book](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/learning-cocos2d-js-game-development). Also javascript can be use as a scripting languages for implement logic instead of lua. We implement that approach in our game. If you want to learn more about it - read [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Javascript_Binding).

And if, for some reasons, you still think you need cocos2dx, I recommend you start with programmers guide (as Michael already advice you) but its too simple and covers only basics. For more advance info you can try to go through [this](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/cocos2d-x-game-development-essentials) or [this](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/learning-cocos2d-x-game-development).

If in some moment you will realize that you need more knowledge about c++, spend some time to learn just c++ itself, since first - it's a very hard language itself and, second, if you interested in game dev, it almost 100% will not be a wasting time.

Last (but not least) great link I want to share with you is [this](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/External_Tutorials). Just go there, after books and found out, what topics you not cover. Also, what even move important, this page provides some game examples so you can analyze some complex game architecture and learn from it.

Good luck!